# Can a BottomSheet be shown behind another view (button)?

Tags: android, material-design

Is it possible to open a BottomSheet behind another view? Like this

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Set button transactionZ value upper than bottom dialog.

```
android:translationZ="90dp
```

Comment: it's not working... another suggestion please?